# Form value not passing in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Here is my app.js, I want to send the value of `email` to the file `handler.php`

```
$scope.doForget={email:''};
$scope.doForget = function (customer) {
     //email = $scope.forget.email; For Testing i am hardcoding the value
     email = 'abc@xyz.com';
     Data.post('handler.php', {
            email: email
        }).then(function (results) {
        console.log(results); 
        }); 
    };
```

In the **Inspect Element -> Networks** i can see the form values as `{email: "abc@xyz.com"}`

In the `handler.php` i use to print the values by `print_r($_POST);` and even `print_r($_GET);` but i am always getting the empty array i.e.,

```
Array
(
)
```

How can i get the values ?

**Update :**

I even tried this one

```
$scope.doForget={email:''};
$scope.doForget = function (email) {
 email = 'abc@xyz.com';
 Data.post('eloquent.php', {
        email: email
    }).then(function (results) {
    console.log(results);
    });
};
```

Comment: How can you get it in networks when you didn't pass email into the post object 0.0?

Comment: Try `post('eloquent.php', {emailNew : email}).then()`

Comment: @Vineet I am getting `ReferenceError: post is not defined` error

Comment: Aren't you using `$http` service ?

Comment: Maybe you can try eliminate the possibility of `Data.post` not implemented correctly by replacing it with `$http.post`?

Comment: Or I suppose you must had assigned refrence of $http into data like - `data = $http`.

Comment: I did like this `$http.post('public/app/api/v1/eloquent.php', { emailNew : email}).then(function (results) {console.log(results);});` and i am getting a very BIG array

Comment: Like this `↵", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}config: Objectdata: ObjectemailNew: "abc@xyz.com"__proto__: Objectheaders: ObjectAccept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"X-`.. Here how can i get the `emailNew` value inside it ?

Comment: @Vineet Yes i missed it and i rectified it. I am getting a large array when i do `print_r` I have posted the array above. How can iget the `emailNew` value ?

Comment: @Icycool Yes, now i changed the way to `$http.post` May i know how can i get only the value of emailNew in the `handler.php` I have posted the array i got in the above comment.

Comment: In PHP remove `print_r` and change it to `echo json_encode($_POST['email'])`, output should look more parsable.

Comment: @Icycool ah, i am getting `data: "<br />↵<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: emailNew` when i do `echo json_encode($_POST['emailNew'])` :( also tried with `echo json_encode($_POST['email'])`

Comment: Hmm the variable name should match with your key in the post.

Comment: @Icycool Yes, now i am doing with the matched key..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use in angular's controller :

```
var emailNew = "demo@demo.com";
  $http({
     method : 'POST',
     url : 'relative_path_to_demo.php',
     data : {"email" : emailNew}
  })
```

and in your server PHP file. Put code

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$objData = json_decode($data);

$email = $objData -> email; // Get your email
```

Comment: I am getting `Object {data: "demo@demo.com
↵
↵", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}`

Comment: Thanks, But why do i get this symbol  `↵ ↵` ?